# Unknown user in terminal

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

Im having a strange problem with the terminal in OS X.

When I open the terminal the username at the command prompt is:

```
unknown-04-0c-ce-e3-0d-c2: ~
```

I can't pinpoint when this first started or why unfortunately.
I usually use iTerm for web development purposes but this also occurs in the normal OS X Terminal app.

Any ideas/help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

**Update:**
Thanks to @fayadfami and @aliasgar for the correct answers and steering me in the right direction.
Also this forum post helped http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=152407
The extract from the right post:

> Having run into the exact same issue myself, and having come across this thread while attempting to figure it out, I thought I'd post the answer.
>
> OS X is initially setting your hostname to what's set for your Computer Name in Sharing; however, if you're set up for DHCP and you match a current lease on your DHCP server (i.e., match the IP address of another recent user), OS X will then set your hostname to whatever the DHCP server currently has for that lease.
>
> This freaked me out incredibly at first, as I had just reformatted (having just purchased my first Mac and wanting to see how the installer worked) and *knew* I had not yet changed the Computer Name in Sharing -- yet my system hostname at the Terminal prompt was indeed changed to what I had previously set, pre-format. I grepped around, not finding the name anywhere save log entries; I thought either the format didn't actually properly wipe everything, or I was losing my mind.   Finally I logged into my router (it's a Linksys WRT54GS running OpenWRT), and found the hostname in the current leases file. I then manually set my Mac's IP to something different, and voila! -- the hostname was back to what I expected.
>
> I hope this helps save someone from the same paranoia I went through.

Comment: which OS version are you running?

Comment: @Josh OS X 10.7.4

Comment: On my Mac, switching the WiFi off and back on fixed this for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- What you see at the prompt at the terminal is a name assigned by your [DHCP Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) appended by your [MAC Address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address)
- The name of your Macintosh has been changed accidentally, or some program / app has changed it explicitly *(or may **NOT** have a name in your case)*.
- Go to `System Preferences` and click on `Sharing`. Change the `Computer Name`. I am attaching the screenshot of the same.

[image: Change mac name]

- Once you do that `Reboot` you Mac. A standard name may look like "Steve Jobs' MacBook." Just personalize this with your own name. And at the prompt it would appear like `Steve-Jobs-MacBook-Pro:~ steve$`

Comment: Thanks aliasgar but this didn't work for me. My machine name is still the same as it was in the Sharing preferences pane. I tried to change it and reboot but it still say unknown in the terminal.

Comment: @GilesB Could it be that your changes are being over written by dhcp name assign? After following @aliasgar's steps and doing a cold reboot look at `/var/log/system.log` closely on the processes starting up while your system boots and if you can find a process responsible for this.

Comment: @fayadfami I just looked at the log file and the first line has the same 'unknown...' username in it, the whole line reads: Aug 26 00:30:02 unknown-04-0c-ce-e3-0d-c2 newsyslog[23504]: logfile turned over

Comment: @fayadfami just spotted this in that log file, any ideas on how to change? Sep  7 00:52:45 Giless-MacBook-Air usbmuxd[58]: _AMDeviceConnectByAddressAndPort (thread 0x100781000): IPv4
Sep  7 00:52:48 unknown-04-0c-ce-e3-0d-c2 configd[16]: setting hostname to "unknown-04-0c-ce-e3-0d-c2.home"

Comment: @fayadfami i got it! You were right, the dhcp name assign was changing it to something on the router. Thanks for all your help mate. This forum post helped - http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=152407

Comment: Glad you could fix it. @fayadfami thank you for helping him out.

Answer (score 4):

A really simple way to sort this out is to simply go to `System Preferences` > `Network` > `Advanced` > `TCP/IP`, and simply make up any old name for the DHCP client ID (below the 'Renew DHCP Lease' button).

Answer (score 1):

There is a great article on how to customize your Terminal prompt over at [OSX Daily](http://osxdaily.com/2006/12/11/how-to-customize-your-terminal-prompt/).  Not sure exactly why yours has changed, but customizing it will get you back to normal... or something different if you  fancy it :)

I'll quote some of the article below:

> The default command line prompt in Mac OS X is something like:
>   `ComputerName:CurrentDirectory User$ or MacBook:~/Desktop Admin$`
>
> Kind of boring and not the best, right? It’s quite easy to change.
>   We’re going to assume you use the default bash shell, so you’ll be
>   editing either the file `.bashrc` by default, or `.profile` if you
>   installed fink. At the Terminal prompt, type: `nano .bashrc`
>
> Now type: `export PS1=" "`
>
> Between the quotation marks, you can add the following lines to
>   customize your Terminal prompt:
>
> - `\d – Current date`
> - `\t – Current time`
> - `\h – Host name`
> - `\# – Command number`
> - `\u – User name`
> - `\W – Current working directory` (ie: Desktop/)
> - `\w – Current working directory`, full path (ie: /Users/Admin/Desktop)
>
> So,
>   let’s say you want your Terminal prompt to display the User, followed
>   by the hostname, followed by the directory, the .bashrc entry would
>   be:
>
> `export PS1="\u@\h\w$ "`
>
> which will look like: `Admin@MacBook~Desktop/$ "`

Comment: Thanks Josh but unfortunately this doesn't work for me either. I end up with: unknown-04-0c-ce-e3-0d-c2: ~                                                                                                
\u@\h\w$ →

Comment: I think i followed a similar article when I originally modified my terminal. Il see if I can find the original, may help.

Comment: This is the article I followed originally to edit the prompt, I think its definitely an issue with the user as editing the prompt is no problem, it still shows an unknown user - http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/how-to-customize-your-command-prompt/?search_index=1

Comment: Ack, sorry to hear that... I'll keep looking :)